# Switching to loaded page after logging in

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, gherkin

anyone care to assist on how can I switch to a new page on another scenario on cucumber, because i cannot click on the link that is loaded on the new page as the compiler complains about unable to locate element. Sorry for not posting the code here, just that it's for an enterprise.

now on new page feature

```
    @Given("^user is logged into Gmail successfully$") 
    public void userIsLoggedIntoGmailSuccessfully(){ 
        //getting current URL driver.get
        ("https://mail.google.com/home/"); 
    } 

    @When("^user navigates to settings link$") 
    public void userNavigatesToSettings() { 
       //this is where all hell breaks loose 
       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'Settings']")).click(); 
    }
```

Comment: The question is not clear.  If sharing code is an issue, then replicate problem with a simple example. Only way someone will be able to understand and help you out...

Comment: `//now on new page feature
  @Given("^user is logged into Gmail successfully$")
    public void userIsLoggedIntoGmailSuccessfully(){

       
  //getting current URL
      driver.get("https://mail.google.com/home/");

    }
 
 @When("^user navigates to settings link$")
    public void userNavigatesToSettings() {

       //this is where all hell breaks loose
    
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'Settings']")).click();
      
    }`

Comment: I noticed that the driver is null when it reaches the last method, cannot pin point where it breaks.

Comment: How are u initializing the driver? Add the code also...

Comment: ` WebDriver driver = null;

    //creating a method
    void createDriver()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver =  new ChromeDriver();
    }
` In this pseudocode, I initialised my driver outside, then I have a method that assigns it to a chrome driver.